# How to concatenate each row horizontally of a string array in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is a numpy string array.

```
Column 1      Column 2      Column 3
A             B             C
a             b             c
A             B             C
a             b             c
```

I would like to concatenate each row horizontally and derive a new array with the same row number like the following:

```
Column 1
ABC
abc
ABC
abc
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there anyway if not using pandas?

Comment: Still, thanks all the same